# Share django lib

Tags: python, django

How share Django lib with multiple python (for example 2.6 and 3.1) ?
A simple way is with ln -s ... is the correct way or is there something a little more clever?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Django doesn't work with Python 3, anyway.

Comment: install the library on the global python path?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using virtualenv for all of your python projects anyway: just install the modules you need for whichever project you are working on, rather than trying to worry about 'sharing'. For modules that compile files, you are probably going to hit problems doing it that way anyway.